# Can't access server since switching to https on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I am deploying a MERN stack using EC2 on AWS.

I have created SSL certificates for the following domains:

```
example.com
*.example.com
www.example.com
```

The cname and cvalue for example.com and *.example.com are identical but they are different for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I have set up target groups and a load balancer and edited the listener to redirect from http to https.

I have set up 3 different records in the hosted zone of route 53 so that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), *.example.com and example.com are directed to the loadbalancer

I can load `https://example.com`

`http://example.com` directs to `https://example.com`

When the website loads (either by typing http or https) it does not connect to the server.

I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://54.220.212.131:5000/events'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

`54.220.212.131` is the site's IP and `5000` is the server's port. This is hard coded in the front end.

How should I get the client to send requests to the server for a https connection?

Comment: On a system that isn't blocking outbound ports, I cannot connect to 54.220.221.131, port 5000.  Did you open it in your AWS security group?

Comment: You should be able to connect to it if you use http://<ip address>. If you just type the ip address, you are brought to https://<ip address> which does not work

Comment: Can you show the Listener configuration of your ALB, target groups and Route 53? If you configure right, your public IP of EC2 should not be there

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two services running, a front-end service that you have correctly configured to run behind a load balancer, and a back-end service that you are connecting directly to via the server's IP address on port `5000`.

Your backend on port `5000` is not secure, and that is exactly what the web browser's error is telling you. You need to configure all your services to run behind the load balancer. You need to create a second target group that sends traffic to port `5000` on your server, and setup a routing rule on the load balancer's listener to send all traffic for `api.ticketglen.com` to that target group. Then you need to change your hard-coded values in from `http://54.220.221.131:5000` to `https://api.ticketglen.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. How do I send all traffic for `api.ticketglen.com` to the target group? I can create a record in route 53 linking that url to the load balancer but that doesn't associate it with a port. The load balancer listener only gives me an option to listen for a port. I don't see an option to listen for a url

Comment: Are you using an Application Load Balancer?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-configure-host-based-routing-alb/

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create the SSL certificates from the server and delete them and the load balancer altogether from the AWS platform.

Process is outlined [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-letsencrypt-ssl-8f463c01502a)